# How can I prevent my model from being overfitted?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm a newbie with deep learning and I try to create a model and I don't really understand the `model. add(layers)`. I m sure that the input shape (it's for recognition). I think the problem is in the Dropout, but I don't understand the value.

Can someone explains to me the

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (128,128,3))) 
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))) 
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))) 

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4), metrics=['acc'])
-------------------------------------------------------
history = model.fit(
      train_data, 
      train_labels,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=(test_data, test_labels),
      )
```

and here is the result :

```
Epoch 15/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3987 - acc: 0.8536 - val_loss: 0.7021 - val_acc: 0.7143
Epoch 16/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 0.3223 - acc: 0.8891 - val_loss: 0.6393 - val_acc: 0.7778
Epoch 17/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.3321 - acc: 0.9082 - val_loss: 0.6229 - val_acc: 0.7460
Epoch 18/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 0.2615 - acc: 0.9409 - val_loss: 0.6591 - val_acc: 0.8095
Epoch 19/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.2161 - acc: 0.9857 - val_loss: 0.6368 - val_acc: 0.7143
Epoch 20/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 0.1773 - acc: 0.9857 - val_loss: 0.5644 - val_acc: 0.7778
Epoch 21/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.1650 - acc: 0.9782 - val_loss: 0.5459 - val_acc: 0.8413
Epoch 22/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1534 - acc: 0.9789 - val_loss: 0.5738 - val_acc: 0.7460
Epoch 23/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.1205 - acc: 0.9921 - val_loss: 0.5351 - val_acc: 0.8095
Epoch 24/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0967 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5256 - val_acc: 0.8413
Epoch 25/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0736 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5493 - val_acc: 0.7937
Epoch 26/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0826 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5342 - val_acc: 0.8254
Epoch 27/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0687 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5452 - val_acc: 0.8254
Epoch 28/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0571 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5176 - val_acc: 0.7937
Epoch 29/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0549 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5142 - val_acc: 0.8095
Epoch 30/30
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0479 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5243 - val_acc: 0.8095
```

I never depassed the 70% average but on this i have 80% but i think i'm on overfitting.. I evidemently searched on differents docs but i'm lost

Comment: please show the training data from model..fit, that is training loss, accuracy and validation loss and accuracy

Comment: And what is the *exact* question?

Comment: i did and my question is how can i improve my model without a overfitting..

Comment: It is overfitting your training data. what is the shape of the training and validation data?

Comment: i think because my acc is at 100% on the last Epoch, i think the training and validation data have a shape of 128,128,3

Comment: I modified your Q title based on your comment here - **my question is how can i improve my model without a overfitting**

Answer (score 0):

Have you try following into your training:

- Data Augmentation
- Pre-trained Model

Looking at the execution time per epoch, it looks like your data set is pretty small. Also, it's not clear whether there is any class imbalance in your dataset. You probably should try stratified CV training and analysis on the folds results. It won't prevent overfit but it will eventually give you more insight into your model, which generally can help to reduce overfitting. However, preventing overfitting is a general topic, search online to get resources. You can also try this

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam, metrics=['acc'])
-------------------------------------------------------

# src: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/
# reduce learning rate by a factor of 0.2 if val_loss -
# won't improve within 5 epoch. 
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.00001)

# src: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/
# stop training if val_loss don't improve within 15 epoch.
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)


history = model.fit(
      train_data, 
      train_labels,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=(test_data, test_labels),
      callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop]
      )
```

You may also find it useful of using [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) or [`LearningRateScheduler`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/learning_rate_scheduler/). This doesn't guarantee of no overfit but some approach for that to adopt.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985765/9215780